# Batch delete - on error, are previous deleted records remain deleted?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-delete

I have a large table with millions of records. When a procedure is executed, it deletes all records older then 20 minutes.

Because, sometimes it take a lot of time, I decided to use batch deletes. I have run some test and it appears that I am gaining 20 seconds optimization, but I have started to wonder, what will happen if an error occurred during one of this delete statements - are previously deleted records remaining deleted or not?

This is the SQL statement:

```
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,-20,GETUTCDATE()) > [TimeAdded])
        BEGIN
            DELETE TOP (500000)
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE,-20,GETUTCDATE()) > [TimeAdded] 

            IF @@ERROR <> 0
                BEGIN
                    RAISERROR (N'Delete operation from ''MyTable'' table failed.',10,0)
                    BREAK 
                END
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

It would ultimately depend on the transactional mode you run this procedure.

But don't mind as it doesn't matter.

The only thing you may do is to log the error, fix the cause of the error and then rerun the code.

In case the first run did delete the records up to the error, rerunning the procedure will resume at the point of the delete error. In case it did not delete the records, rerunning the procedure will delete them.